# Definition of stress-energy tensor

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

[image]

The image from the wiki article on the stress energy tensor gives $T_{00}$ as $1/c^2$ times the energy density.  I believe this is incorrect and that the $1/c^2$ factor should be dropped.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the correct units for the energy-momentum tensor?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22143/finding-the-correct-units-for-the-energy-momentum-tensor)

Answer (score 3):

The stress-energy tensor can be written with $T_{00}$ as an energy density or a mass density. The latter is of course just $E/c^2$ in accordance with Einstein's famous equation $E=mc^2$. Both forms are used and neither is more correct that the other.

In any case general relativists usually choose units where $c=1$ and the distinction disappears.

Comment: Thank you John Rennie, but then the pressure diagonal (for instance) should be pressure divided by c squared shouldn’t it?  If the wiki author puts in c’s and G’s then (s)he should be consistent no?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct and Wikipedia is wrong. Energy density is $Nm/m^3 = N/m^2$ in SI units. Pressure is also $N/m^2$. Dividing $T^{00}$ by $c^2$ makes no sense.

Comment: The other row that needs correction is the momentum density.  If we drop the 1/(c squared) factor from T00 then we have to multiply the momentum density by a factor of c.  The pressure and shear stress components remain unchanged.

Comment: @Polhode I agree. Looking at the talk page of the Wikipedia article, it seems one of the contributors insisted on working with a metric that has different units for different tensor components, which makes the article super-confusing. The Wikipedia article on [the electromagnetic stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) is much  clearer in this regard.