# Formation of Black Hole

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, event-horizon, density

Black holes are formed when energy is put in a small region of space, I was wondering if there is a threshold to how much energy should I add in a certain volume of space to get a black hole, I read about the Schwarzschild radius formula that tells us the radius of event horizon of black hole formed by a star of mass $M$. My question is that is there any relation between energy and volume of a region to form a black hole?

Can I use Einsteins Energy-mass equation to find the energy and substitute the value of mass in terms of energy in the formula of Schwarzschild radius so that I have a relation between radius of event horizon and energy contained in it and calculate volume accordingly?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26515/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5888/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use
$$E=mc^2$$

in combination with
$$r_s=\frac{2GM}{c^2}$$

to calculate the energy required to form a Schwarzschild black hole of a given Schwarzschild radius.

However, in General Relativity, gravity isn't *just* caused by the amount of energy (including rest mass energy) in a region. The [Einstein field equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) say that the spacetime curvature is due to the [stress-energy-momentum tensor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor).

[image: stress-energy-momentum]

So to properly calculate the gravity as a black hole forms we also need to include the effects of pressure, momentum density, momentum flux, and shear stress.

That pressure term is very important. Normally in a star, there's an equilibrium between the gravity that's trying to compress the star, and the pressure due to temperature that's trying to expand the star. When a large star is on the verge of becoming a supernova, the temperature and pressure in the star core become enormous. And because the pressure is so large it increases the gravity, leading to a feedback loop that rapidly collapses the core, initiating the supernova explosion and the formation of the black hole remnant.

---

I should mention that that Wikipedia article is a little controversial. Please see the answers and comments [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/388442/123208) for details.

Comment: the matrix is very useful, thanks for including it here. -NN